# Using eval in Julia to deal with varargs

Tags: eval, julia

I have just started using Julia. I am trying to use eval (in Julia) in order to define a set of variables in a function. Let's say I want to set v1 equal to 2:

```
function fun_test(varargs...)
  v1 = 0;

  if length(varargs) > 0
    j = collect(linspace(1,length(varargs)-1,length(varargs)/2));

    for i in j
      expr_vargs = parse("$(varargs[i]) = $(varargs[i+1]);");
      eval(expr_vargs);
    end
  end

  println(v1)

end
```

Calling the function as:

```
fun_test("v1", "2");
```

It doesn't work, since println returns 0 (the initial value of v1). However, if I run an analogous eval call in the Julia's terminal, then it works.

Could you please clarify why it doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: your `expr_vargs` is fine. It's the `eval`...

Comment: Hi @Memming. Could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: `eval` works in the global scope, but `v1` is local because of the line `v1=0`.

Comment: Thanks, is there any alternative in Julia to run a string as an expression in local scope? I have just seen that you might eval an entire function to do what I wish, but I would prefer to avoid it.

Comment: As @ChrisRackauckas notes, `eval` works in the global scope. Other relevant StackOverflow questions (using google): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267962/how-can-i-eval-a-local-variable-in-julia http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882241/eval-in-function-scope-accessing-function-args http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174352/julia-speeding-up-eval

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eval` runs in [toplevel scope](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/#Base.eval), not in function scope. It is not possible to dynamically update bindings in function scope. Without knowing your precise use case, I suspect there is a way to do things without dynamic rebinding. In particular, `v1`, `v2`, etc. is probably best made into an array, `V`.

Nevertheless, if you *really* must, you can always define `v1` as a global variable in a submodule:

```
module FunTest
v1 = 0
function fun_test(varargs...)

  if length(varargs) > 0
    j = collect(linspace(1,length(varargs)-1,length(varargs)/2));

    for i in j
      @eval $(varargs[i]) = $(varargs[i+1])
    end
  end

  println(v1)

end
export fun_test
end
using .FunTest
fun_test(:v1, 2)  # result: 2
```

(I have also modified your code to avoid `parse`ing strings, which is best done through [expression interpolation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Metaprogramming#Expression_interpolation).)